# NuGet Hide Files in Visual Studio

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2012, nuget

Question:
Is there a way to copy the files over in the NuGet, but have it not load the folder into the Visual Studio solution?

Explanation:
I am working on a NuGet Package that adds files to be used by the user. So I add the files to the NuGet Packages like so:

```
<files>
    <file src="Commands\*" target="Content\Commands" />
    <file src="Settings\*" target="Content\Settings" />
    <file src="Scripts\*"  target="Content\Scripts" />
</files>
```

By doing this all the folders are visible when you add the NuGet to your Visual Studio project.

The problem is that I do not want anyone to manipulate the "Scripts" folder. So I want it to not be visible or loaded into the Visual Studio Solution. But I need it in the packages folder for it to work properly. I know people will alter it if they choose to, but I am just trying to see if I can hide it so that they do not have it in their solution.

I have been looking at the documentation and I do not think it allows it, but was curious if anyone knows a way to achieve it.